# How to move or Transfer row in database java

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to move row in sqlite java.  I thought about taking the values ​​of the row, then deleting it, then adding id + 1, then adding the row, but this does not work, id unique. Is there an easier way?

> ex:
> Transfer id to id2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mark |
| 2 | john |
| 3 | smith |
| 4 | tom |

Change to:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | john |
| 3 | smith |
| 4 | mark |
| 5 | tom |

```
String n=Db.getName(id);
Db.delete(id);
Db.transId(id2);
Db.insert(id2,n);

void transId(int id){
sq.execSQL("update table set id=id+1 where id>="+id);
}
```

> error:

```
Exception: dispatching input event
UNIQE constraint failed: table.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555])
```

Comment: What do you mean by *move row*?

Comment: For example: Transfer a row from posistion 1 to posistion 3 in sqlite

Comment: There is no such thing as position of a row in a table. Tables are unordered datasets.

Comment: @forpas Yes, but the order is by id. What I mean is how can this be done in an easier way: for example in table (id,name): **1 john , 2 mark , 3 smith , 4 tom **  >>> **2mark , 3 smith , 4 john , 5 tom**

Comment: there is no point in doing that

Comment: [A] remove the constraint. Or, [B] disable constraint checking, update the IDs, re-enable constraint checking. Or, [C] bounce through unused IDs, e.g. first set them all to `SET id = -id`, and _then_ to the desired value, `SET Id = -id+1`. Or [D] set up the constraint to check only at commit.

Answer (score 0):

A-(id1=fromid;id2=toid) //add+1 (id2)

```
Update table set id=-id where id>id2
Update table set id=-id+1 where id<id2
```

B detNAME(id1) and delete(id1)

C insertRowId(id2+1,name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).